# My phpexcel code unable to read server files

Tags: php, regex

I can read excel files on my hard drive but not on my server. What am I doing wrong. Windows 7

```
if (!file_exists("\\s-fs2\Attachments\FLine2.xlsx"))
```

Comment: How are you connecting to the server exactly? That would probably be useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your slashes look to be going the wrong way:

```
if (!file_exists("/s-fs2/Attachments/FLine2.xlsx"))
```

On `Unix`, `Linux`, `OSX`, `FreeBSD`, etc. file paths use forward slashes. If you're using an SMB server or something such as that you may be missing the protocol on the front too:

**For Example:**

```
smb://s-fs2/Attachments/FLine2.xlsx
```

Comment: I tried forward and backward slash so it must be a protocol issue. Is there so where I can read up on or get a list I can try

Comment: @jimneely, How are you connected to the server?